# How to incorporate timeout while sending message to the JMS destination using Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Web service with Weblogic server. On each request I send JMS message to the JMS destination using JMSTemplate. Following is my spring configuration.

```
<int:channel id="input" />

<int:channel id="output">
    <int:dispatcher failover="true" load-balancer-ref="failoverStrategy" />
</int:channel>

<bean id="failoverStrategy" class="c.x.FailoverStrategy">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <list>
            <ref bean="synMessageDispatcher" />
            <ref bean="failoverHandler" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<int:channel id="xml" />

<int-xml:marshalling-transformer
    input-channel="input" output-channel="xml" marshaller="marshaller"
    result-type="StringResult" />

<int:object-to-string-transformer
    input-channel="xml" output-channel="output" />

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="contextPath" value="c.x.domain" />
</bean>

<bean id="failoverHandler"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
        <bean class="java.io.File">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="./synfailed" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    <property name="appendNewLine" value="true" />
    <property name="autoCreateDirectory" value="true" />
    <property name="charset" value="utf-8" />
    <property name="expectReply" value="false" />
</bean>

<bean id="pollableFileSource"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource"
    p:filter-ref="compositeFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="failedMessageComparator" />
    <property name="scanEachPoll" value="false" />      
    <property name="directory">
        <bean class="java.io.File">
            <constructor-arg index="0" value="./synfailed" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="synMessageDispatcher" method="run"
        fixed-rate="10000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="compositeFilter"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.CompositeFileListFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.integration.file.filters.SimplePatternFileListFilter">
                <constructor-arg index="0" value="*.msg"/>              
            </bean>         
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

I use the bean custom "failoverStrategy" which is working fine in certain scenarios.

If there are no requests from the client and if JMS goes down then the subsequent request is successfully handled by the "failoverHandler" (which is simply persisting the messages to the file system.

If there is a continuous flow of the requests from the client and if JMS goes down then I face the stuck thread at the `jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator()`. Since there is no time out property the request is stuck forever and I have to restart the weblogic server! Kindly suggest how to resolve this problem.

Following code snippet shows how I am sending the JMS message

```
try {

        jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {

            @Override
            public javax.jms.Message createMessage(Session arg0)
                    throws JMSException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                TextMessage message = arg0.createTextMessage(text);
                // message.setIntProperty(MESSAGE_COUNT, index);

                log.debug("Sending message: " + text);

                jmsAvailable = true;

                return message;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MessagingException(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Following is my JMS related configuration.

```
@Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() throws JMSException {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setConnectionFactory(cachingConnectionFactory());
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(syn_mpg_queue);

        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory()
            throws JMSException {
        CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
        cachingConnectionFactory
                .setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        cachingConnectionFactory.setSessionCacheSize(10);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setReconnectOnException(true);
        cachingConnectionFactory.setCacheProducers(true);
        return cachingConnectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
        TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory targetConnectionFactory = new TibjmsQueueConnectionFactory();
        targetConnectionFactory.setServerUrl("tcp://" + jmsServerIp + ":"
                + jmsServerPort);
        return targetConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> if JMS goes down then I face the stuck thread at the jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator()

If JMS "goes down" you should get an exception; the first step is to find out where it is "stuck", by taking a thread dump using jstack or similar.

If the thread is stuck in the weblogic JMS client and is uninterruptible, there's nothing the framework can do to help.